# How to get widget from a QStandardItemModel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How to get the widget from a 'QStandardItemModel' using known '(row, colum)'.

First, I create the table

```
# initialize the model
Mymodel = QStandardItemModel(1, 2)
Mytable = QTableView()
Mytable.setModel(Mymodel)
```

Then I add the Label widget at 'column=1'

```
# add QLabel
l1 = QLabel()
l1.setText('Peter Alice')
Mytable.setIndexWidget(Mymodel.index(1, 1), l1)
```

I used the 'Mytable.selectionModel()' to get the selected row to be deleted. But first, I need to grab the 'text' from the 'l1'.

```
row, column = Mytable.selectionModel().selectedRows().row(), 1
label = Mytable.model().index(row, column).data()    # it gives None
name  = label.text()
```

The approach above '.data()' gives None. How can I grab the corresponding label

The task is to Get the text of that widget at index

Comment: Why are you using a label while you could just set the value for the item?

Comment: `Mytable.indexWidget(Mytable.model().index(row, column))`.

Comment: @ekhumoro, thanks !